# String to date conversion not working correctly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I need to get time difference in this format: "HH:MM:SS" using a Javascript.

I have tried this:

```
var diff = Date.parse( time2) - Date.parse( time1 );
var total_time = (diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) + ":" + (diff / 1000 / 60) + ":" + (diff / 1000);
```

and this:

```
var diff = new Date( time2) - new Date( time1 );
var total_time = (diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) + ":" + (diff / 1000 / 60) + ":" + (diff / 1000);
```

These are the values of time2 and time1:

```
time1: "2012-11-07 15:20:32.161"
time2: "2012-11-07 17:55:41.451"
```

And result I am getting in both cases is:

```
total_time= 0.5250819444444444:31.504916666666666:1890.295
```

Which you can see is not correct

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel :) [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: If he really just needs the difference at one point building it yourself might be better than including yet another library. Plus it's nice exercise. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to remove the number of milliseconds you already calculated from `diff`. Here is a very verbose example on how you do it in a propper way.

```
var time1 = "2012-11-07 15:20:32.161",
    time2 = "2012-11-07 17:55:41.451",

    SECOND = 1000,
    MINUTE = SECOND* 60,
    HOUR = MINUTE* 60;

var diff = new Date(time2) - new Date(time1);

var hours = Math.floor(diff / HOUR); // Calculate how many times a full hour fits into diff
diff = diff - (hours * HOUR); // Remove hours from difference, we already caluclated those
var minutes = Math.floor(diff / MINUTE); // Calculate how many times a full minute fits into diff
diff = diff - (minutes * MINUTE); // Remove minutes from difference
var seconds = Math.floor(diff / SECOND); // As before
diff = diff - (seconds * SECOND);
var rest = diff;

var total_time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + rest ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nm7Ka/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting **wrong diff value** because of the **millisecond part in the date delimited by `.`. Its not being accepted correctly by the data parser.**

Try using the date and time part excluding the milliseconds as below:

```
 var diff = Date.parse(time2.split(".")[0]) - Date.parse( time1.split(".")[0]);
```

Also while you are getting wrong difference `diff`, **your time computation is also wrong.**

It should be:

```
       var second = Math.floor(diff /1000);
        //convert the seconds into minutes and remainder is updated seconds value
       var minute = Math.floor(second /60);
       second = second % 60;

        //convert the minutes into hours and remainder is updated minutes value
       var hour = Math.floor(minute/60);
       minute = minute %60;

       var total_time= hour+":" minute+":"+second;
```

Comment: Well when I run your or mine code on jsfiddle it puts `2:35:9` out which is clearly the correct difference, including the `.` for the milliseconds.

Comment: thank you, your code is working also but @clentfort has a lower rating so I'll raise his rating a bit :)

Comment: @clentfort: I don't see any difference in both the answers in the way you are computing the difference. As I highlighted, its parser issue, which is not coming when you use `new Date()`.

Comment: Thanks. :) I actually prefer this method above mine since it is not that verbose. I choose the more verbose way to show you where the problem was.